# Neural Network - ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm new in Python and Tensorflow . For the beginning I watched the MNIST tutorial and understood it so far.

But now I have to create a new Neural Network with numerical input_datas.
I got a dataset which delivers an input_data and v_data.

If I run input_data.shape -> (1000,25,4)

If I run v_data.shape -> (1000,2)

What I tried to do is to split the data for (Training + Validation) and Testing.

- Training + Validation = 90% of train_data (90% of the input.pkl)
- Testing data = the remaining 10%

And then I devided the 90% of the input_data in training and validation (70% training, 30% validation)

The network should correctly predict based on v_data, but I still get an error. See the code and the error below.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# Imports
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle as pkl
import numpy as np

# load data
with open('input.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    input_data = pkl.load(f)
    f.close()

X_train, y_train = input_data


#split data into train / validation and test
X_input = X_train[0:900]
y_input = y_train[0:900]

#print (X_input.shape)
#print (y_input.shape)

X_train_data = X_input[0:630]
X_test_data = X_input[630:900]

y_train_data = y_input[0:630]
y_test_data = y_input[630:900]

# Variables
hidden_layer_1_nodes = 300
hidden_layer_2_nodes = 100
output_layer_nodes = 100
epochs = 10
classes = 2
epoch_errors = []
stddev = 0.035
learning_rate = 0.08
batch_size = 100

#print (X_train_data[0])

# TF Placeholders
X = tf.placeholder('float', [25, 4], name='X')
y = tf.placeholder('float', name='y')

# Weights Matrices
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4, hidden_layer_1_nodes], stddev=stddev), name='W1')
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_layer_1_nodes, hidden_layer_2_nodes], stddev=stddev), name='W2')
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_layer_2_nodes, output_layer_nodes], stddev=stddev), name='W3')
W4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([output_layer_nodes, classes], stddev=stddev), name='W4')

# Biases Vectors
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_layer_1_nodes], stddev=stddev), name='b1')
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_layer_2_nodes], stddev=stddev), name='b2')
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([output_layer_nodes], stddev=stddev), name='b3')
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([classes], stddev=stddev), name='b4')

# Define the Neural Network
def nn_model(X):
    input_layer     =    {'weights': W1, 'biases': b1}
    hidden_layer_1  =    {'weights': W2, 'biases': b2}
    hidden_layer_2  =    {'weights': W3, 'biases': b3}
    output_layer    =    {'weights': W4, 'biases': b4}

    input_layer_sum = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, input_layer['weights']), input_layer['biases'])
    input_layer_sum = tf.nn.relu(input_layer_sum)

    hidden_layer_1_sum = tf.add(tf.matmul(input_layer_sum, hidden_layer_1['weights']), hidden_layer_1['biases'])
    hidden_layer_1_sum = tf.nn.relu(hidden_layer_1_sum)

    hidden_layer_2_sum = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_layer_1_sum, hidden_layer_2['weights']), hidden_layer_2['biases'])
    hidden_layer_2_sum = tf.nn.relu(hidden_layer_2_sum)

    output_layer_sum = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_layer_2_sum, output_layer['weights']), output_layer['biases'])
    return output_layer_sum

# Train the Neural Network
def nn_train(X):
    pred = nn_model(X)
    pred = tf.identity(pred)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        #saver = tf.train.Saver()
        sess.run(init_op)

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0.0

            i = 0
            while i < len(X_train_data):
                start = i
                end = i+batch_size

                batch_x = np.array(X_train_data[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(y_train_data[start:end])

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i+= batch_size

            epoch_errors.append(epoch_loss)
            print('Epoch ', epoch + 1, ' of ', epochs, ' with loss: ', epoch_loss)

        correct_result = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_result, 'float'))
        print('Acc: ', accuracy.eval({X:X_test_data, y:y_test_data}))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nn_train(X)
```

The following error

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 25, 4) for Tensor 'X:0', which has shape '(25, 4)'

occurs in line 105

> _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: batch_x, y: batch_y})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The placeholder you have defined for the input X has the shape (25,4)

```
tf.placeholder('float', [25, 4], name='X')
```

But the input you are providing is of the shape (100, 25, 4) where 100 is your batch size.
Change the definition to

```
tf.placeholder('float', [None, 25, 4], name='X')
```

and the error should be gone. Here, `None` takes care of batch size, automatically.

**Update:** Sorry, I didn't go through the whole code. You code needs a few fixes.
The correct syntax for feeding data to a placeholder is:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_dim], name='X')
```

Now, if you are dealing with the images, your input_dim will be the length of the flattened array for one example i.e. If your image has dimension 25x4, the input_dim should be 25*4=100. It should be equal to the first dimension of your weight layer 1 here `W1`.
Also, before feeding your batch you will need to reshape it.

Below is the fixed code(changes are commented):

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# Imports
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle as pkl
import numpy as np

# load data
with open('input.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    input_data = pkl.load(f)
    f.close()

X_train, y_train = input_data


#split data into train / validation and test
X_input = X_train[0:900]
y_input = y_train[0:900]

#print (X_input.shape)
#print (y_input.shape)

X_train_data = X_input[0:630]
X_test_data = X_input[630:900]

y_train_data = y_input[0:630]
y_test_data = y_input[630:900]

# Variables
hidden_layer_1_nodes = 300
hidden_layer_2_nodes = 100
output_layer_nodes = 100
epochs = 10
classes = 2
epoch_errors = []
stddev = 0.035
learning_rate = 0.08
batch_size = 100

#print (X_train_data[0])

# TF Placeholders
# input data should be of the shape (batch_size, flatten data for one example). Also, the correct shape of y"
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 25 * 4], name='X')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, classes] name='y')

# Weights Matrices. First dimension of W1 == second dimension of X
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([25 * 4, hidden_layer_1_nodes], stddev=stddev), name='W1')
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_layer_1_nodes, hidden_layer_2_nodes], stddev=stddev), name='W2')
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_layer_2_nodes, output_layer_nodes], stddev=stddev), name='W3')
W4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([output_layer_nodes, classes], stddev=stddev), name='W4')

# Biases Vectors
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_layer_1_nodes], stddev=stddev), name='b1')
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_layer_2_nodes], stddev=stddev), name='b2')
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([output_layer_nodes], stddev=stddev), name='b3')
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([classes], stddev=stddev), name='b4')

# Define the Neural Network
def nn_model(X):
    input_layer     =    {'weights': W1, 'biases': b1}
    hidden_layer_1  =    {'weights': W2, 'biases': b2}
    hidden_layer_2  =    {'weights': W3, 'biases': b3}
    output_layer    =    {'weights': W4, 'biases': b4}

    input_layer_sum = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, input_layer['weights']), input_layer['biases'])
    input_layer_sum = tf.nn.relu(input_layer_sum)

    hidden_layer_1_sum = tf.add(tf.matmul(input_layer_sum, hidden_layer_1['weights']), hidden_layer_1['biases'])
    hidden_layer_1_sum = tf.nn.relu(hidden_layer_1_sum)

    hidden_layer_2_sum = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_layer_1_sum, hidden_layer_2['weights']), hidden_layer_2['biases'])
    hidden_layer_2_sum = tf.nn.relu(hidden_layer_2_sum)

    output_layer_sum = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_layer_2_sum, output_layer['weights']), output_layer['biases'])
    return output_layer_sum

# Train the Neural Network
def nn_train(X):
    pred = nn_model(X)
    pred = tf.identity(pred)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        #saver = tf.train.Saver()
        sess.run(init_op)

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0.0

            i = 0
            while i < len(X_train_data):
                start = i
                end = i+batch_size
                # reshape before feeding.
                batch_x = np.array(X_train_data[start:end]).reshape(batch_size, 25 * 4)
                batch_y = np.array(y_train_data[start:end]).reshape(batch_size, classes)

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i+= batch_size

            epoch_errors.append(epoch_loss)
            print('Epoch ', epoch + 1, ' of ', epochs, ' with loss: ', epoch_loss)

        correct_result = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_result, 'float'))
        print('Acc: ', accuracy.eval({X:X_test_data.reshape(-1, 25 * 4), y:y_test_data.reshape(-1, classes)}))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nn_train(X)
```

Comment: Kumar, thanks for your answer.

I changed it to 

    tf.placeholder('float', [None, 25, 4], name='X') 

But get the following error out of it:

    ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,25,4], [4,300]. 
in line 70:

    input_layer_sum = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, input_layer['weights']), input_layer['biases'])

Comment: @newcomer updated the answer on how to fix the errors.

Comment: thanks for your support. Unfortunately I receive the following error: 
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3000 into shape (100,100) for batch_x = np.array(X_train_data[start:end]).reshape(batch_size, 25 * 4).

Comment: Okay. I got it. The error comes because in your last batch there are only 30 examples. You can either ignore them or change your batch size to be integer divisor of your training data size.

Comment: please see below

Comment: Same reshaping process you have to do for your test batch as well to fix the error. If by "weird" you mean huge loss, you may want to consider scaling your input data.

Comment: I tried, but get every time another error of it :/ After all I fixed the "weird" huge loss. But I still need help with the reshaping

Comment: copy the whole code again from above and tell me what error are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: Sorry I posted the wrong error:**
@Kumar, I changed the batch size to 30 (so 21*30 = 630). It prints now the epochs, but in some weird way:

```
Epoch  1  of  10  with loss:  1680690.2648780346
Epoch  2  of  10  with loss:  2382142.9208984375
Epoch  3  of  10  with loss:  4215628.857421875
Epoch  4  of  10  with loss:  9046892.295166016
Epoch  5  of  10  with loss:  23961644.453125
Epoch  6  of  10  with loss:  31733882.34375
Epoch  7  of  10  with loss:  46124696.609375
Epoch  8  of  10  with loss:  61760446.28125
Epoch  9  of  10  with loss:  89145610.59375
Epoch  10  of  10  with loss:  121249417.25
```

And I received a next error for:

```
 print('Acc: ', accuracy.eval({X:X_test_data, y:y_test_data}))
```

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (270, 25, 4) for Tensor 'X:0', which has shape '(?, 100)'

Process finished with exit code 1